# Replace space with only inside quotes using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like:

```
" smth, value, 'val ', ' name surname' "
```

And I want to replace the white space inside quotes with `¤`  so the result will be:

```
" smth, value, 'val¤', '¤name¤surname' "
```

Please, is there any way to do it with regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex to find text in quotas. Then use simple string replace

```
var input = " smth, value, 'val ', ' name surname' ";
var result =  Regex.Replace(input, "'(?<text>[^']+?)'", m =>
{
    var replacement = "¤";
    return $"'{m.Groups["text"].Value.Replace(" ", replacement)}'";
});
```

Comment: Great is working but what if we have double quotes and single quotes?

Comment: @bramzoti It would be better if you ask a new question with examples of input and expected output

Answer (score 0):

From [C# Tutorials](https://csharp.net-tutorials.com/regular-expressions-regex/search-replace-with-the-regex-class/)  :

```
Regex regex = new Regex(" (¤^ ¤+) ");
string cleanString = regex.Replace(testString, "[$1]");
Console.WriteLine(cleanString);
```

Comment: I added your and mine solution to [netfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oYQHVa). I don't think your code work as OP expected

Comment: My bad... I've don't read good the topic. Thanks yoo for reviewed my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can used this one too which will handle all possible whitespace with space.

```
    string temp = " smith, value,' val ',' name surname'";

        Console.WriteLine("Before  Replace :: "+ temp);
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"[\s\'][\s\']");
        string t = regex.Replace( temp,"@");
        Console.WriteLine("After Replace :: "+ t);
```

Comment: This does not work correctly. You also have to match between name and surname.